# Horizontal Timeline in Vuetify 2 / ipyvuetify

Tags: vuetify.js, ipyvuetify

I'm working with `ipyvuetify` and trying to use the `v-timeline` component from Vuetify 2.x but I would like to get a horizontal timeline instead of the default vertical one.

I've tried going through the documentation [here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-timeline/) but couldn't find any information.

I am aware of the [direction](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/pull/13566) prop from Vuetify 3.x and the [vue-horizontal-timeline](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-horizontal-timeline) packages but would like to do this in native Vuetify.

Thanks!